# correlative comparative structures with "the"

Tags: parallelism, comparative

I wonder which sentence sounds more natural as well as grammatically correct?

> The more you start disliking her, **the more actively** your memories of her will be faded from your mind.

> The more you start disliking her, **the more actively faded** your memories of her will be from your mind.

Comment: delete is for computers. We would say: the more your memories of her will fade.

Comment: The first order is much more natural. The second one is very hard to read.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie and gotube!

Comment: @gotube IMHO the first one reads even better without **be**.